# Enable bitlocker and save key to share

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I have searched all over the web but cannot find a complete answer to this:
How to enable Bitlocker on a laptop with TPM, and store a file with the Bitlocker recovery key and TPM password by USING THE manage-bde command line tool. The file should be the same as when created in the Bitlocker manager UI. I DO NOT want to save to AD. The same question was asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/318492/enable-bitlocker-and-save-key-to-network-share-with-unattend) but was not answered correctly.

The goal is to write a script to be used with an endpoint manager.

I have tried the following:

```
manage-bde -on C:
```

Works fine, but does not create or save a key.

```
manage-bde -on C: -rk C:\myfolder\
```

and

```
manage-bde -on C: -RecoveryKey C:\myfolder\ -rp
```

The output from the last two methods state that a key has been saved to c:\myfolder and so on, but that is not the case. It also says that I have to:

1. Save the password in a secure location
2. Insert a USB flash drive with an external key file into the computer.
3. Restart and run hardware test
4. type "`manage-bde -status`" to check if the hardware test succeeded

After a restart, I get an error saying that Bitlocker could not be enabled because

> the bitlocker startup key or recovery kpassword cannot be found on the
>   USB device.... C: was not encrypted.

Why am I asked to insert a USB?? I simply want to encrypt the hard drive and save the recovery information to a file automatically. Is that too much to ask?

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done for the recovery password (not key). Not fancy, but works - maybe it can point you in the right direction

manage-bde -on C: -recoverypassword > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\printthisout-then-storesecurely.txt

Answer (score 1):

The keys are actually saved, but they have SHR attributes, so you can't see them.

Try this to see the file

```
dir *.* /a:s
```

or

```
attrib -s -h -r *.*
```

Comment: The second one worked for me, thanks. After running that in the USB directory, I can see the .BEK files.

Answer (score -2):

Setting up TPM owner password:

```
manage-bde -tpm -o PASSWORD
```

Creating a folder with computer name in your network shared folder
called `bitlocker`:

```
md "\\path\bitlocker\%computername%"
```

Creating a text file with name of computer:

```
manage-bde -on C: -rp -rk "\\path\bitlocker\%computername%" -s > "\\path\bitlocker\%computername%\%computername%.txt"
```